# Vietnamese font for web

Tags: html, fonts, meta

I'm doing some webpage testings and having a problem with Vietnamese input.

The result going to be something like

```
Ä‘c Äƒn Noel á»Ÿ
```

I tried some font like Arial and Times New Roman but none of them is helping me with this trouble. Any idea what font or what techniques I should use to avoid this?

For future references, is there a same way for another languages (like chinese...)

Edit:

This is my header code of the input page

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Tri Nguyen"/> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, Tri Nguyen, Tree Nguyen"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Tri Nguyen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/message.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="image_src" href="./tree.jpg" />
    <script src="./JS/message.js"></script>
    <title>Message</title>
</head>
```

And this is the HTML code for the input

```
<span id="maintext">What do you want to say &#9829;<br/><br/></span>
<textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" ></textarea>
<br/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set encoding of your site in metadata?

Comment: @Justinas <meta charset="utf-8"/>

Comment: Is this what you are talking about? @Justinas

Comment: Show what you have actually tried, HTML code and HTTP headers. It very much looks like an encoding problem, not a font issue. (Asking for fonts for specific purposes would be off-topic at SO.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela have just addede

Comment: There are no Vietnamese characters (except Basic Latin characters) in the code, and no actual style sheet settings are shown. And the code bears no resemblance to the sample display. If you are just asking why input of Vietnamese characters, using some unspecified input method(s), does not work for you in some browser in some platform, I’m afraid it’s off-topic here (but you might ask at SuperUser, *with a real description* of the situation).